# Can I use both deprecated OpenGL and modern OpenGL in a single rendering window?

Tags: opengl, opentk

I am developing a project using modern OpenGL through OpenTK. I want to use Gwen dot net GUI library in my project. Unfortunately, Gwen dot net uses old OpenGL for its widget rendering. I have tried merging both modern OpenGL and Gwen dot net and so far, have been unsuccessfull. Before I waste my time debugging my code, I would like to know, is it possible to merge both old OpenGL and modern OpenGL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a compatibility profile context, it should support all all legacy functionality. From [OpenGL 4.3 compatibility spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec43.compatibility.20130214.pdf), 1.2.4:

> Older generations of graphics hardware were not programmable using shaders,
> although they were configurable by setting state controlling specific details of their
> operation. The compatibility profile of OpenGL continues to support the legacy
> OpenGL commands developed for such fixed-function hardware, although they
> are typically implemented by writing shaders which reproduce the operation of
> such hardware. Fixed-function OpenGL commands and operations are described
> as alternative interfaces following descriptions of the corresponding shader stages.

Answer (score 1):

These days mixing old style and new style OpenGL is best avoided. On MS Windows and Linux you can, but weird stuff tends to happen.

For MacOS, Apple have declared that they're not going to support compatibility contexts at all, so you can't mix.

Since you're stuck with the GUI toolkit, I would try to isolate all your new style OpenGL code in a separate context and render to an offscreen target, then blit that to the main display.

Comment: Apple's OpenGL programming guide states otherwise: *(https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_pixelformats/opengl_pixelformats.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH214-SW9): "... include the kCGLOGLPVersion_Legacy constant.
The legacy profile provides the same functionality found in earlier versions of OS X, with no changes. It continues to support older extensions as well as deprecated pixel and buffer format attributes. No new functionality will be added to the legacy profile in future versions of OS X."

Comment: @MuertoExcobito He means that a 4.0 compatibility is not available while 4.0 core and 2.0 compatibility is available.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito Yes, even 3.x compatibility is not available on the Mac. You can choose either 2.1 or a 3.x/4.x core profile.

Comment: But, there *is* a compatibility context, and, it's doubtful that Apple will take it away, otherwise all legacy GL applications will stop working (eg. Apple 'declaring' they're not supporting compatibility contexts = not true). The OSX 2.1 compatibility context gives quite a lot of "modern" GL functionality via extensions. They likely just won't expand it the list of extensions it supports, as their documentation states.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito: I think this is a matter of terminology. OSX does not support the compatibility profile (and consequently comaptibility contexts) at all.OpenGL introduced core and compatibility profiles in version 3.2, hence "OpenGL 2.1 compatibility contexts" do not exist. GL versions before that are nowadays referred to as "legacy".

Comment: @derhass I would say you are right, that my statement was wrong, 'compatibility contexts' were introduced with 3.2, thus, the 2.1 context is not a compatibility context. Regardless of semantics, the answer is still incorrect in saying mix modern OpenGL and legacy OpenGL usage in an OSX context is not possible.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito I write MacOS OpenGL programs. If you ask for a core profile in MacOS, you get one that only supports the modern OpenGL 3/4 API and none of the 1.x/2.x backwardly compatible features. If you don't specifically ask for a core profile, you get 2.x with various extensions for 3/4 capabilities.

Comment: @HughFisher I think we've established that my comment and your answer were not exactly correct. Also, the OP never said that he was using OSX specifically. If you are on a platform that does give a compatibility profile, the fact is that you can use legacy and modern features in a single context. On OSX, you can still use modern GL features by using extensions in a 2.1 context.

Answer (score 0):

OpenTK render for GWEN is a separate class. Just rewrite it modern way. There's no problem with that.